# Intuit Partner Platform QBD API v2: Invoice create / update doesn't seem to recognize item Amount, Price & Quantity

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I am trying export Invoices from my app to QuickBooks Desktop. The invoice gets created, and I get a success message, but the QuickBooks Desktop app does not reflect the Amount, Price or Quantity sent through the API.

Here is a request / response example of one such operation:

Request:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Mod xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2" RequestId="6ffd7874b723b84ad2eba8146c12fda1">
  <ExternalRealmId>MY_REALM_ID</ExternalRealmId>
  <Object xsi:type="Invoice">
    <Id idDomain="NG">2064384</Id>
    <SyncToken>4</SyncToken>
    <Header>
      <DocNumber>100009</DocNumber>
      <TxnDate>2013-10-16</TxnDate>
      <Status>Pending</Status>
      <CustomerId idDomain="QB">2</CustomerId>
      <CustomerName>Jenny Cliff</CustomerName>
      <RemitToId idDomain="QB">2</RemitToId>
      <RemitToName>Jenny Cliff</RemitToName>
      <ShipDate>2013-10-16</ShipDate>
      <SubTotalAmt>950.0</SubTotalAmt>
      <TaxRate>0.0</TaxRate>
      <TaxAmt>0.0</TaxAmt>
      <TotalAmt>950.0</TotalAmt>
      <ToBePrinted>true</ToBePrinted>
      <ToBeEmailed>false</ToBeEmailed>
      <ARAccountId idDomain="QB">40</ARAccountId>
      <ARAccountName>Accounts Receivable</ARAccountName>
      <DueDate>2013-10-17</DueDate>
      <BillAddr>
        <Line1>217 E Washington Ave,</Line1>
        <City>Sunnyvale</City>
        <Country>USA</Country>
        <CountrySubDivisionCode>CA</CountrySubDivisionCode>
        <PostalCode>94086</PostalCode>
        <Tag>Billing</Tag>
      </BillAddr>
      <ShipAddr>
        <Line1>217 E Washington Ave,</Line1>
        <City>Sunnyvale</City>
        <CountrySubDivisionCode>CA</CountrySubDivisionCode>
        <PostalCode>94086</PostalCode>
        <Default>false</Default>
        <Tag>Shipping</Tag>
      </ShipAddr>
      <Balance>950.0</Balance>
    </Header>
    <Line>
      <Desc>Test Item 1</Desc>
      <Amount>500.0</Amount>
      <UnitPrice>500.0</UnitPrice>
      <Qty>1</Qty>
    </Line>
    <Line>
      <Desc>Test Item 2</Desc>
      <Amount>450.0</Amount>
      <UnitPrice>450.0</UnitPrice>
      <Qty>1</Qty>
    </Line>
  </Object>
</Mod>
```

Response:

```
<RestResponse xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2">
  <Success RequestId="6ffd7874b723b84ad2eba8146c12fda1">
    <ObjectRef>
      <Id idDomain="NG">2064384</Id>
      <SyncToken>5</SyncToken>
      <LastUpdatedTime>2013-10-16T17:45:06Z</LastUpdatedTime>
    </ObjectRef>
    <RequestName>InvoiceMod</RequestName>
    <ProcessedTime>2013-10-16T17:45:06Z</ProcessedTime>
  </Success>
</RestResponse>
```

Documentation reference can be found [here](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2/0500_quickbooks_windows/0600_object_reference/invoice).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per the documentation:

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2/0500_quickbooks_windows/0600_object_reference/invoice

For each  node you specify, you MUST also specify an Item node. From the docs:

- ItemId
- IdType
- *Required*
- ID for the Item object. A reference to the Item is required for the Create operation, either the ItemId or ItemName; ItemId is preferred.

Change your XML request so that you're referring to an item.

This mirrors the behavior of the QuickBooks GUI.